# How to connect my external hard drive to be used with System Repair disc(Restore Img)

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, window, system-repair-disc

I made a few months back a backup of my machine (Windows 7 64bit edition). The size was like 25gb's so I saved it on my external hard-drive(I bought a case and put a hard drive(Seagate I think) in it).

I know want to use this to restore my computer. So I made a system repair disk and loaded it up.

However it cannot find my external hard-drive. I have "WindowsImageBackup " in my root directory of my external drive.

Yet it still does not see it. I would install some drivers but I have no clue what drives I need as when I plug it into my computer and I am in Windows 7 it finds my drive.

What do I need to make Windows 7 recognize my image?

Comment: Make and model of external drive? Connection type, USB?

Comment: USB conntection with a seegate barracuda 1TB driver.

Comment: Did you try using different usb ports?

Comment: You may be able to get drive recognized by patching the Windows 7 installer to include the necessary drivers. Take a look at vLite, though you may need a slightly different program for Win7. Is it an option to just connect the hard drive to the machine internally?